# JQuery scrolling not working in Internet Explorer or Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, firefox

I am using some JQuery to show/hide some action buttons on a new parallax scrolling webpage that I am currently building. Once you scroll PAST 100px it shows the actions buttons. If you scroll back up, the action buttons disappear.

It works perfectly in Chrome, but is not working in Firefox or Internet Explorer. I am using other JQuery on the page and it is firing correctly in Firefox and Internet Explorer.

[Live demo of the parallax scrolling site](http://www.msj.edu/landing-pages/parallax-scrolling)

[JSFiddle of the code in question](http://jsfiddle.net/tagriffith/wLtpwmq8/1/)

Here is the code in question:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
slider();

});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    slider();
});

function slider() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 100)
        $('#request').stop().animate({"bottom": '10'});
    else
        $('#request').stop().animate({"bottom": '-75'});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After some digging around further, I found out that Firefox and IE identify the "top" differently so I changed the code from:

```
if (document.body.scrollTop > 100)
```

to:

```
if  ($(window).scrollTop() + 1 > 100)
```

and the code works perfectly!